# Unable to open any websites using Selenium Webdriver with Chromedriver in Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automation-testing

The browser opens with Se WD but the websites do not open. I have looked at [Selenium opens browser but not site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504988/selenium-opens-browser-but-not-site)
and [When running WebDriver with Chrome browser, getting message, "Only local connections are allowed" even though browser launches properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080500/when-running-webdriver-with-chrome-browser-getting-message-only-local-connect) among other related articles but none of them seem to work.
I have tried it with Java 1.8, Se WD 4.7 and 4.8 with Chrome 111 and ChromeDriver for Chrome 111 version.

I tried running the code as Java application with simple code just to get started with Selenium as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com/");`
```

Here is my log:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64 (c710e93d5b63b7095afe8c2c17df34408078439d-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#995}) on port 34274
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Mar 28, 2023 12:17:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.abort(WebSocketHandler.java:92)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.WebSocketHandler.handleRead(WebSocketHandler.java:118)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.AsyncHttpClientHandler.channelRead(AsyncHttpClientHandler.java:78)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:54082/devtools/browser/01808d58-14d7-4401-8b5f-cf479860cccb
Build info: version: '4.7.0', revision: '52e3a49ea2'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:49)
    at newpackage.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:23)
```

Please advice.

Comment: Try URL with HTTPS.

Comment: as you can see in your error message you get an 403 error code - that means you are not allowed (forbidden) to browse that content - google uses https (not http) protocol, so change `driver.get("http://google.com/");` to `driver.get("https://google.com/");`

Comment: I have tried both, same error. The issue is not http vs https here

Comment: I can not even mark the answer as valid as I have "low" reputation. Perhaps, you guys can Up the question so I can atleast mark the solution as worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

In the latest chrome version occurs this issues, By adding this argument --remote-allow-origins=* your problem will solved

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I am curious to know how you got to this solution? I tried googling, stackoverflow, stackexchange, baeldung etc for possible solutions but nothing had worked

Comment: I can not even mark the answer as valid as I have "low" reputation. Perhaps, you guys can Up the question so I can atleast mark the solution as worked?

Comment: Thank you @SumitM, Happy to know it helps you. I found a solution last week when I suffer from this problem after updating the chrome driver.